# How to calculate what percentage of a pixel is within the bounds of a shape

Tags: graphics, antialiasing, typography, rasterizing

I have a 2d grid where pixel centers are at the intersection of two half-grid lines, as shown below.
[image]

I also have a shape that is drawn on this grid. In my case the shape is a glyph, and is described by segments. Each segment has a start point, end point and a number of off-curve points. These segments can be quadratic curves or lines. What's important is that I can know the points and functions that make up the outline of the shape.

The rule for deciding which pixels should be turned on is simple: if the center of the pixel falls within the shape outline, turn that pixel on. The following image shows an example of applying this rule.
[image]

Now the problem I'm facing has to do with anti aliasing. What I'd like to do is to calculate what percentage of the area of a given pixel falls within the outline. As an example, in the image above, I've drawn a red square around a pixel that would be about 15% inside the shape.

The purpose of this would be so that I can then turn that pixel on only by 15% and thus get some cleaner edges for the final raster image.

While I was able to find algorithms for determining if a given point falls within a polygon ([ray casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)), I wasn't able to find anything about this type of problem.

Can someone can point me toward some algorithms to achieve this? Also let me know if I'm going about this problem in the wrong way!

Comment: The easiest way is probably super-sampling: Check not only the pixel center but a whole bunch of points in the pixel. If you want to be exact, you have to calculate the intersection of the shape and the pixel area. This can become tricky.

Comment: @NicoSchertler A technique like super-sampling is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. It's a great starting point for me to read up on the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an X, Y problem.

You are asking for a way to calculate the perecentage of pixel coverage, but based on your question, it sounds that what you want to do is anti alias a polygon.

If you are working only with single color 2D shapes (i.e red, blue, magenta... squares, lines, curves...) A very simple solution is to create your image and blur the result afterwards.

This will automatically give you a smooth outline and is simple to implement in many languages.

Comment: I think that this is definitely not a bad solution, and it would probably work in most cases. However I can imagine cases where the blurring of a pixel would result in a bad value, such as a pixel that only overlaps the outline by a small percentage, but is surrounded by pixels that are completely on.

Comment: My advice is, try it out, it will take you about 15 minutes to implement, you canuse OpenCV for example.

See if it performs well or not for your purposes and then decide. Don;t let the best be the enemy of the good.